# To show heading direction on blue pulsating dot(user's current location) without loosing accuracy circle 

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager, compass-geolocation

I have a CLLocation manager as follows

```
myLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    myLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
    myLocation.delegate=self;
```

if device supports heading information then method is called to update heading

```
if([CLLocationManager headingAvailable])
        [myLocation startUpdatingHeading];
```

and change in heading are retrieved from following method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    [mymap setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * newHeading.trueHeading * 3.14159 / 180)];

}
```

I can use this information (newHeading.trueHeading) to rotate the map. But how can I show a sector that will depict heading direction with given or forced accuracy, on blue dot (indicator of users current location).   I am able to use custom image for blue dot but it looses light "accuracy circle" then. Is there any way to get a reference to the blue dot view and modify it, so that accuracy circle is not lost.

Also rotation of annotations can be avoided with negative rotation but when map is rotating the "Title" and "subTitle" of annotations gets extended beyond view of visible screen. Is there any way to limit them to map's view.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this project](https://github.com/d0n13/MapTest) as a guide. It rotates the whole mapView, but you can extrapolate it to your view.

**EDIT:** If you want to customize the userLocation annotation you have to implement viewForAnnotation and check if the given annotation is  `MKUserLocation` and return a custom annotationView configured as you want.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        //Configure your custom view to point to the current heading and return it.

    }

}
```

Comment: I can rotate the map according to value obtained from newlocation.trueheading but still I cannot modify the blue dot(users current location) to show users Heading. I have edited question to show changes that I made.

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
        if (newHeading.headingAccuracy > 0) {
                // [newHeading retain];
             float heading = newHeading.trueHeading >= 0 ? newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading;


             [mymap setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading)];


        }
    }
```